# Value is not visible in grid column after grid load

Tags: devexpress-wpf, devexpress-gridcontrol

I have written below code to show a DatePicker and Textbox control for a column.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
    <ContentControl>
      <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="{Binding DisplayText}" AllowEditing="True" Visible="True">
            <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings> 
                 <dxe:TextEditSettings DisplyFormat="{}"/>
            </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings> 
            <dxg:GridColumn.EditTemplate>
               <ControlTemplate> 
                 <Grid>
                    <Grid.Definitions>
                         <Column.Definition Width="20"/>
                         <Column.Definition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.Definitions
                    <DatePicker x:Name="myDate" Grid.Column="0" SelectedDate="{Binding                     
                                   Path=RowData.Row.Date, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    </DatePicker>
                    <TextBox x:Name="myText" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=RowData.Row.Text, 
                                        Mode=TwoWay}">
                    </TextBox>
                 </Grid>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn.EditTemplate>
      </dxg:GridColumn>
    </ContentControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

on cell click I can see the controls in column cell however on loading of grid data is not visible in cell and also after cell leave value is not shown.

Could anyone let me know if I am making any mistake?
Thanks in advance